# Compare two data.frames to find similar values from data.frame 1 in data.frame 2

Tags: r, merge

I have two data.frames: name and searches

```
name <- data.frame(
  A = c("example", "firstly", "second.com")


searches <- data.frame(
  A = c("example.com","secondly","first"),
  B = c("test", "test.com", "test1"))
```

I want to search in data.frame "searches" for the values in data.frame "name". If there is a similar value (not exactly the same) I want R to return the value from name and from searches in a new row in a new table.

So a new data.frame could be

```
result <- data.frame(
    A = "example", "firstly", "second.com",
    B = "example.com","first","secondly",
    C = "test", "test1", "test.com")
```

Is that possible?

Comment: How do you define "similar"?  Here it looks like having the same 4 first letters is enough - is that so?

Comment: Yes indeed, I think the content in data.frame "searches" should contain 4 similar successive letters from the content of data.frame "name"

Comment: If it's always just the first four letters, then you can `merge` on frames with an extra column created with `substring(..., 1, 4)`. If it's something different, though, you might consider the [`fuzzyjoin`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stringr` package in R to do this. For example, if you have

```
name <- data.frame(
  A = c("example", "firstly", "second.com"))


searches <- data.frame(
  A = c("example.com","secondly","first"),
  B = c("test", "test.com", "test1"))
```

then you can use

```
str_extract(searches$A, '.*example.*')
```

This gives an output of

```
> str_extract(searches$A, '.*example.*')  
[1] "example.com" NA            NA
```

If you set this up with an appropriate for loop to iterate over elements in your `name` dataframe and cells of your `searches` dataframe then you could pick up all matches and extract them as desired.

Answer (score 0):

use the function stringdist_join from the fuzzyjoin package.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

name <- data.frame(
  A = c("example", "firstly", "second.com")
)

searches <- data.frame(
  A = c("example.com","secondly","first"),
  B = c("test", "test.com", "test1")
)

result <- stringdist_join(name, searches, by = "A", max_dist = 5)
```

Which results to:

```
> print(result)
         A.x         A.y        B
1    example example.com     test
2    firstly       first    test1
3 second.com    secondly test.com
```

Comment: that looks perfect, unfortunately I get an error: 
Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `col` is NULL

Do you know what is going wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what causes this problem. Do you use the exact same data.frames as you listed above or did the error occur after testing on the entire database (assuming there is one)? What version of R are you using?

Comment: Yeah the data frames are kind of the same. I am using R version 1.2.1335. I still haven't been able to fix it.. If you have any idea how to fix this it would be great

Comment: It's a problem with tibble. Fuzzyjoin uses the package somewhere in the stringdist_join function and that causes the issue. But for me it is hard to say where the problem lies exactly, even with the exact data in hand.